# Sinon Stub the whole class

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I have the below class in `A.js` file,

```
class A {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getResult() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

module.exports = A
```

In other file called `controller.js`, I'm using like this,

```
const A = require('./A');

module.exports = {
    doProcess: () => {
        const a = new A('John');

        console.log(a.getResult());
    }
}
```

So my requirement is, I want to stub the class A and its methods while writing the unit tests for `controller.js`. How can I achieve this using sinon ?

Something like,

```
const getResultStub = sinon.stub();
getResultStub().returns('success');
```

Comment: What about `Factory` pattern? You can use it in controller and later mock.

Answer (score 0):

If it is default export, I don't believe you can directly stub it.

If you are working in nodejs environment, You can either use [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire), or do something like:

```js
// A.js

class A {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getResult() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

module.exports = A
```

```js
// controller.spec.js

const sinon = require('sinon')

class DummyA {
  constructor(){}
  getResult(){
    return 'success'
  }
}

require.cache[require.resolve('./A')] = DummyA

const controller = require('./controller.js')
```

Comment: I'm fine to use proxyquire, but could you suggest the solution using it either ?

Comment: you mean the solution without `proxyrequire`? Just note that I am not a nodejs expert, but here is my understanding: when node `require` a module, it will first determine the absolute path of the module by running `require.resolve`, then checking if it has already been required in `require.cache` dictionary.

Comment: (incidentally, you can do `console.log(require.resolve('./A'))` and check the output)

Comment: The *other* method effectively populates the `./A` module in the `require.cache` dictionary

Comment: btw, i think i quoted the wrong package... it might have been [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) instead